# Prevent other apps to access my app's image stored in sd card

Tags: android, storage, file-permissions, android-sdcard

In my application, I have created a bitmap and save it as a JPG image in the SD card. I don't want any other apps to use this image. Is this possible in android ? Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Android does not allow other app's to use your data. There's nothing that you need to do.

Comment: but the image is publicly available know ?

Comment: @Anirudh That's only in *internal* storage, not on SD card

Comment: I guess a file manager in a rooted phone can access any file in it?

Answer (score 8):

Unless you encrypt the file, there is nothing you can do to prevent access to files on the SD card.
(See the section on external storage [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal))

> Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be
>   modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer
>   files on a computer.

Instead consider putting it in [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), then  your application will be the only one that can access it.

Another option, if you only need to hide it from media scanners is to either give it a name that starts with a dot (`.myfile.jpg`) this will make it a hidden file. (if you have multiple files you want to hide this way, include an empty file with the name `.nomedia` (see [Saving files that should be shared](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)) so you don't have to rename them all)

Answer (score 1):

When storing the image, change the extension of the file to something else, so other apps would not recognize it. But when you want to use it in your app, change the extension back to .bmp or .jpg!

Comment: This does not prevent enything – just obfuscates acces

Comment: Check this ,it may helpful for you https://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-prevent-a-directory-from-being-scanned-by-android-gallery/

Answer (score 1):

Use an application specific database and save your images there instead saving it on the SD-Card. Then only your application has access. I'm doing this to encrypt the images in my application, just saving a BASE64 encoded image string doing crypto stuf on it and vice versa. This would also work if you save a Byte Array of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 – Creating A .nomedia File .

Using any file explorer/manager application (such as Astro File Manager or File Expert), navigate to the directory that you want hidden and create an empty file titled “.nomedia”.One way to do so is to:

Copy an existing text (.txt) or even an image (.jpg/.jpg) file to said directory,
Open it in a text editor (hold down on the file and select the appropriate option from the context menu that appears),
Delete its contents (hold down on the text, Select all and Delete), save changes and exit,
Rename it to “.nomedia” (hold down on the file again and select Rename from its context menu).
This method disables media scanning on the chosen directory, causing the Gallery to skip the directory altogether at launch.

[image]